# Make @JsonView annotation on controller action include properties by default

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

When you use Jackson's `writerWithView` any properties that don't have a `@JsonView` annotation on them are still serialised. However using `@JsonView` on a Spring MVC action seems to require `@JsonView` to be on every property.

If say we have the following model:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String emailAddress;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    @JsonView(DetailView.class)
    public String getEmailAddress() { return emailAddress; }
}
```

And `DetailView` extends `BasicView`, when I serialise with basic view I'd expect `username` to be serialised. This is what happens when we use `writerWithView`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getMe() throws JsonProcessingException {
    User user = getCurrentUser();
    return objectMapper.writerWithView(BasicView.class).writeValueAsString(user);

 }
```

However from Spring MVC 4.1 we can instead do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/me", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
@JsonView(BasicView.class)
public User getMe() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return getCurrentUser();

 }
```

The later causes the response to be `{}` rather than `{username:"David"}`. If we add `@JsonView(BasicView.class)` onto the `getUsername()` this works as expected.

Obviously we could go with the former or add `@JsonView` to everything, both of which are more verbose and error prone.

This looks a bit like `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` has been turned off, but explicitly enabling it doesn't seem to have worked.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` being disabled is indeed the problem, but unfortunately the Spring classes don't give an easy way to configure or replace the ObjectMapper used by the default message converters.

The neatest way I found to work around this was to extend `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` and override `configureMessageConverters` to populate the default converters and then overwrite the problematic `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration;
import com.example.config.serialization.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverterWithCustomObjectMapper;

import java.util.List;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan({/*...*/})
public class MyWebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //...
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        super.configureMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        if (messageConverters.isEmpty()) {
            addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        }

        messageConverters.replaceAll(converter -> {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper());
            } else if (converter instanceof AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter) {
                return new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverterWithCustomObjectMapper(objectMapper());
            }
            return converter;
        });
    }

}
```

For completeness you may also want to substitute the `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`, as above, with your own copy that also allows specification of an `ObjectMapper`.  I've not included the `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverterWithCustomObjectMapper` class here - it's a trivial copy of `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` that forwards an `ObjectMapper` constructor parameter to the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that it creates.